# Returning multiple values in a view using Flask (Python)

Tags: python, flask, view

I'm struggling to even understand this in my head from a broad point of view, but I'll try explain as best as I can, if anything isn't clear please comment asking for more information.

Right now I have a python function that fetches a users name and their user ID from an internal API in my workplace that is tied to the username of each worker, this is then routed to a web page with a table like so. (I use the username as the main way of retrieving the data, i guess it could be considered the primary key?)

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def issue(username)

    json = get_json(username)

    _user = get_username(json)
    _id = get_id(json)

    print "User: " + _user
    print "ID: " + _id
```

(The `get_username()` and `get_id()` functions parse through the JSON file and retrieve the data that I need)

The way users get to this page is at the main page of the webapp there is a text field, they type in a username, it then redirects them to the page 127.0.0.1:5000/user/username , which in turn calls that function above.

This gives a very simple web page with just the username and the ID. However, how could I render multiple names and ID's with one request.

So for example:

```
1. User goes to home page
2. User enters "John Doe, Harry Smith, Alex Boggs" into the text box and hit submit
3. They are then presented with this information

User: John Doe
ID: 127

User: Harry Smith
ID: 412

User: Alex Boggs
ID: 322
```

I'm not really sure where to even begin to do this, as I only really know how to pass one argument at a time.

**Note: Ideally the data wouldn't actually be tied to a URL, and instead would just generate below the search box on the homepage, but I will settle for any solution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user enters `John Doe, Harry Smith, Alex Boggs` in text box then you should get `John Doe, Harry Smith, Alex Boggs` in Flask and you have to split it `"John Doe, Harry Smith, Alex Boggs".split(", ")` to get list of names.

Now you can use `for` loop to print User, ID for every name.

Answer (score 0):

Use "path" converter like this `@app.route('/something/<path:name_list>')`
So when user request the URL: `site/something/name1/name2/name3`
you will get a name list

Or you can create your own converter by create a converter class.

```
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter
class ListConverter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, data):
         return data.split(',')

    def to_url(self, data)
         ','.join([BaseConverter.to_url(each) for each in data])
```

Then add this converter to application converter dict like this:

```
app.url_map.converters['list']=ListConverter
```

Now you can use your list converter to implement that function:

```
app.route('/something/<list:name_list>')
```

And user can request the URL like: `site/something/name1,name2,name3`